# My app stop in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

My app stop in AppDelegate.
I am making an app which can access camera and photo library and I can upload photos in my app.
I run my app in my real iPhone from Xcode,but when I put camera access button & photo library button, my app stopped in a part AppDelegate.swift

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

and could not move.
In Cornroller,I wrote

```
import UIKit

class KenshinSendController:UIViewController,
UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{

    let ButtonCamera = 0
    let ButtomRead = 1
    let ButtonWrite = 2

    var imageView:UIImageView  = UIImageView()
    var btnCamera:UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    var btnRead:UIButton  = UIButton(type: .custom)
    var btnWrite:UIButton  = UIButton(type: .custom)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(imageView)

        btnCamera.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
        btnCamera.setTitle("Camera", for: .normal)
        btnCamera.tag = ButtonCamera
        btnCamera.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnCamera.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        self.view.addSubview(btnCamera)

        btnRead.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100)
        btnRead.setTitle("Read", for: .normal)
        btnRead.tag = ButtomRead
        btnRead.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnRead.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(btnRead)

        btnWrite.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: 100, height: 100)
        btnWrite.setTitle("Write", for: .normal)
        btnWrite.tag = ButtonWrite
        btnWrite.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btnWrite.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.view.addSubview(btnWrite)
    }

    //ボタンクリック時に呼ばれる
    @IBAction func ButtonCamera(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    @IBAction func ButtonRead(_ sender: Any) {
    }
    func onClick(sender:UIButton){
       if sender.tag == ButtonCamera {
          openPicker(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)
       }else if sender.tag == ButtomRead {
           openPicker(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary)
        }

    }

    //アラートの表示
    func showAlert(title: String?, text: String?) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: text, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func openPicker(sourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceType){
        if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType){
            showAlert(title: nil, text: "利用できません")
            return
        }

        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = sourceType
        picker.delegate = self

        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
           }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as! UIImage
        imageView.image = image

        picker.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true,completion:nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


}
```

Identity Inspector is like
[image]

and AppDelegate.swift is like

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Info.plist is like

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>フォトライブラリの使用許可をお願いします</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>カメラの使用許可をお願いします</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Error message is like `Thread 1:signal SIGABRT`
I used TabBarController,it is like
[image]

Connection Inspector is like
[image]

[image]

Comment: Share error message (may be printed in your console). Your app delegate is default and correct.

Comment: thx ur comment,I add my info.

Comment: Please share this (your) sample project (complete source code), will check & revert you with solution.

Comment: @KrunalBhavsar which source code do u think?

Comment: Current one, you have added in snapshot, if it is not confidential and you are still facing problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to give photo and camera access in `info.plist` file.

`Privacy - Camera Usage Description`

`Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description`

Comment: Up voted. FYI, here's a link that may help explain: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/privacy-settings-in-ios-10/

Comment: thx,ur comments.But I did it already.What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, and it's perfect, there is no error in your code.

It seems, you have a wrong link with Interface Builder element in your storyboard. Reason for this kind of error is, wrong link (attachment) of interface builder in storyboard with your view controller.

Please check your initial storyboard & especially initial view controller, its attachment with connection inspector & Identity inspector.

- **Identity Inspector**: Your view controller is properly integrated with current project or not.
- **Connection inspector**: You don't have any wrong link of interface builder.

*Share here snapshot of your initial storybaord & view controller also, with identity inspector and connection inspector.*

**Edit:** According to your current snap shot, you may have used Tabbar controller as initial view controller (and two connections are incoming for current view controller you have shared.) but not shared information about tabbar controller here. Share complete snapshot (and source code) of your story board to get exact resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The following answers about iOS 10 will only affect the app's review process and will build and run without errors, so adding these will change nothing in a sense of the app's ability to work:

```
Privacy - Camera Usage Description: purpose of your app using camera
Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description: purpose of your app using Photo
```

The issue you are experiencing is usually due to a broken reference your storyboard. You may have changed an outlet name or an IBAction method.

You can check this by selecting the view controller in the storyboard and looking for a `!` next to any references. If there is a `!`, click the X to delete the reference.

See attached image (look at down arrow)

[image]

You can also look in the code for an empty circle next to your outlets or actions.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

From iOS 10, you have to add privacy descriptions in your info.plist file unless your app will crash when request permission. In your case, you must add:

```
Privacy - Camera Usage Description : purpose of your app using camera
Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description : purpose of your app using Photo
```

Comment: thx,ur comments.But I did it already.What should I do to fix it?